# Ionic data storing like sharedpreferences?

Tags: angularjs, html, authentication, ionic-framework, datastore

Hello everyone I am kinda new for ionic framework.I need your help.
What do you suggest me to store user's data(username , password or loginkey....).

Does it help me to use html5 local storage? I want user to use the application after login till he logout even turn off the mobile device.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way you can use localstorage , localstorage will be cleared only if the app is uninstalled ...

Comment: thank you, So can you suggest me anything like session?it must be destroyed after I closed to application.

Comment: For session you can use angular cookies  Just Follow the link http://maffrigby.com/maintaining-session-info-in-angularjs-when-you-refresh-the-page/     Happy Coding :)